# MySQL check if text date is between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to check whether a date in my database is between two dates.  The column in the database is in the following format:

```
March 2015
```

The sql query i'm looking to create is this, but it doesn't work:

```
select * from table where timesheet_report_month between 'November 2014' and 'March 2015'
```

Comment: Those aren't dates. Those are strings. This is why you should only store dates as dates and not strings. This would be trivial to do.

Comment: So there's no way to do it?

Comment: What's your table data format? date? datetime? timestamp? or just "varchar"?

Comment: See my answer for how to do this

Comment: You really want to store your dates in a MySQL date format especially if you are going to use the column as part of the query for selecting rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert those strings into dates. Then you can take advantage of MySQL's date functionality:

```
select * 
from table 
where STR_TO_DATE(timesheet_report_month, '%M %Y') 
    between '2014-11-01' and '2015-03-31'
```

See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the formatting specifiers.

Comment: Plus 1, but you're assuming that `timesheet_report_month` is in a date format.

Comment: I think that timesheet_report_month is the column that needs to be parsed.